# Automatically sync a local repo when changes occur in remote repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-clone

Say we have a remote repo 'HelloWorldRemote' and I already cloned a local repo from the same, say 'HelloWorldLocal'. Is it possible to set up an automatic git sync HelloWorldLocal with changes from HelloWorldRemote whenever any new changes/commits happen on HelloWorldRemote?
Is this possible in either GitHub or GitLab?

Comment: Not really, you have to either run `git fetch/pull` periodically or set up a synchronization mechanism outside of git.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a git-hook on the remote to trigger some action on your local machine, but that would require:

- a process running locally that listens for a network message, and does some carefully-crafted automatic `git pull` that handles any and all errors that will come up
- exposing that process to the remote git server, via ssh/proxy/etc
- configuring a git-hook to use that ssh/proxy/etc tunnel to tell your local process to do its thing

It would be better to simply use git as intended: `git fetch` manually, and see for yourself what has changed. Or, if your local repo is literally just a read-only copy of the upstream repo that you never commit to, cron a `git pull` every X minutes.